# Why do I lose Bootstrap Dropdown Menus when I use local files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been using Bootstrap for abt a year now, and it works nicely. But when I try to use the files locally, it's always the same result: my Navbar dropdown menus stop dropping down.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title></title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <!-- Place favicon.ico in the root directory -->

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/plugins.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Errors are:

```
wsschedulepolygraphs.php:14 GET http://localhost/dfwit/js/jquery.min.js 
wsschedulepolygraphs.php:17 GET http://localhost/dfwit/js/jquery-ui-1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js 
bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery(anonymous function) @ bootstrap.min.js:6
dropdown-enhancement.js:267 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined(anonymous function) @ dropdown-enhancement.js:267
wsschedulepolygraphs.php:434 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ wsschedulepolygraphs.php:434
wsschedulepolygraphs.php:530 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Comment: Have any errors in your console when you run it locally?

Comment: check your browser console to verify none of the includes are failing to load.

Comment: I do have errors:  two `403 (Forbidden)` and one `404 (Not Found)`. Thing is, these are on my server, and on my local box, too. The `403` files have `rw - r - r` permissions set. Is that wrong? And not sure what to make of the `404`, because that file is definitely there.

Comment: @Landslyde is jQuery within the 'dfwit' folder? Those read permissions look okay, so it might pay to possibly look at directory permissions / owner - http://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory

Comment: @RepeatQuotations - yes, JQuery is in the `dfwit/js` folder. It was a permission issue. Thanks for your input. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Landslyde Great to hear! I'll post it as an answer so you can mark accepted.

Comment: @RepeatQuotations - Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incorrect permissions on a directory can cause 403 and other access errors when reading files. To check owner and group of the current directory from the command line:

```
~$ ls -ld
drwxr-xr-x  2 owner group 4096 Aug 12 19:12 Desktop
```

Sources:
[How to Find Owner and Group of a Directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175054/how-to-find-owner-and-group-of-a-directory)

https://superuser.com/a/91966

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the code, your path for bootstrap differs from all the other JavaScript includes.

```
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            ^^^

<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            ^^^
```

Comment: I fixed that, but no success from it. I posted new results that reflect  correcting that path.

Comment: So is the jQuery file actually loading?

Comment: No, it isn't. Why would that be? The file is in the `js` folder where I'm calling for it. But it's definitely not loading.

Comment: `chmod +r jquery.min.js`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much for your help and insight.

Answer (score 0):

The path of the js files is not correct. Also for the below code the / before the js could cause an issue

```
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```